# Sumar uno a una variable que contiene la informacion de un txt python

Tags: python

buenas mi duda trata es de que leo un archivo

```
archivo = open("archivo.txt",'r')
eje_y = archivo.read()
archivo.close()
```

hasta aquí fácil imaginémonos de que el contenido es recto y aquí es donde viene la duda

```
eje_y = eje_y + 1
```

esto no me funcione me salta el siguiente error:
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
alguien sabe como solucionar

Comment: `eje_y = int(archivo.read())`

Comment: funciona perfectamente muchas gracias